# Connect to Oracle 12c Database from Grails

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

How do I configure Grails web app to connect to a simple (one table!) Oracle 12c database?  I've been through a bunch of tutorials already, and each one is either incomplete or out of date.  I need a simple, hand-holding, step-by-step tutorial.  I understand that GORM is based on Hibernate, and somehow it's all taken care of under the hood, but I can't get a simple connection working.  I've glanced over the Grails documentation but it seems to favour H2 and MySQL connections, not really Oracle.

So I understand that I have to modify DataSource.groovy, to replace the default H2 settings.  Below is my attempt at modifying DataSource.groovy for my Oracle 12c database:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username = "scott"
    password = "Sc0ttSc0tt"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            pooled - true
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = 'scott'
            password = 'Sc0ttSc0tt'
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.105:1521:orcl"
            dbCreate = "validate" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''           
        }
    }

    test {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = 'scott'
            password = 'Sc0ttSc0tt'
            url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.105:1521:orcl'
            dbCreate = 'validate'
        }
    }

    production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = 'scott'
            password = 'Sc0ttSc0tt'
            url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.105:1521:orcl'
            dbCreate = 'validate'
        }
    }
}
```

Then I understand that I can somehow use "Scaffolding" or GORM or whatever else to map domain classes to the database table... which is where I'm stuck, and am either not drinking enough coffee or have missed something.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modifying Datasource.groovy is enough to connect to a database you need. So what's the actual issue with connection? Any errors/ exceptions?

Comment: by the way, if you define properties in the dataSource global property, you don't have to redefine it in the environment blocks

Comment: @lukelazarovic - java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an older dialect, "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" is the one you need. (At least for me connecting to a Oracle11gR2 DB)
The dialect you are using is for Oracle9g and before for my experience.

Comment: Thanks, using that dialect solved one issue.  I also trimmed down the development, test and production settings so that they inherited the default pooled, driverClassName, username and password.  I know that these will be different in a real life scenario, but the inherited properties seemed to fix this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the Datasource.groovy file, and making the changes recommended above by mwaisgold, I finally got the following format to work:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = "scott"
    password = "Sc0ttSc0tt"
}

hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    //    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.103:1521:orcl"           
        }
    }

test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.103:1521:orcl"               
    }
}

production {
    dataSource {            
        dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
        url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.103:1521:orcl"
    }
}
```

}